# Что лучше @ResponseStatus или ResponseEntity?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, controller

Какой вариант предпочтительнее по вашему мнению?

```
@PostMapping(value = "/create")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public Student createStudent (@RequestBody Student student) {
    return service.createStudent(student);
}
```

или

```
@PostMapping(value = "/create")
public ResponseEntity<Student> createStudent (@RequestBody Student student) {
    return new ResponseEntity(service.createStudent(student), HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Использование `ResponseEntity` позволит Вам задавать `location` в заголовке ответа, что более выгодно для передачи информации к браузеру.

Тогда Ваш метод должен выглядеть так:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/create")
public ResponseEntity<Student> createStudent (@RequestBody Student student) {
     Student student = service.createStudent(student);
     URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{yourPath}").
                buildAndExpand(student.getName()).toUri();
     return ResponseEntity.created(location)
                          .body(student)
                          .build(); 
}
```

В данном коде `yourPath` это путь к Вашему сервлету (контроллеру), а `student.getName()` - информация, описывающая конкретного студента.

`Mozilla` говорит следующее насчет такого подхода:

> Код ответа состояния успеха HTTP 201 Created указывает на то, что запрос был выполнен успешно и привел к созданию ресурса. Новый ресурс фактически создается до того, как этот ответ будет отправлен обратно, и новый ресурс возвращается в теле сообщения, его местоположением является либо URL-адрес запроса, либо содержимое заголовка Location.